# Need to print the captured user signature in the specified position in java

Tags: java, zebra-printers

We will capture the user signature through the tablet. (We are done that part)
Now we need to replace the captured signature with "$Signature" in the below content and send to printer.

"The content is something similar to the below.
I hereby declare that, to the best of my knowledge and belief, 
the particular given  above and the declaration  made therein are true.

Name $Name
Date $date
Signature $signature"

we need some solutions in java

Comment: HTML5 will send to my action class as a Base64Enc string.
I converted the Base64Enc sting as a image using ImageIO. 
Sample code is below.
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(uservo.getSignature());
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bis);
File ImageDataFile = new File("D:\\test.jpg");
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", ImageDataFile);
bi.flush();
bis.close();

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to replace String with some other String, you can use the `replace()` method of the `String` class. For example:

```
String name = "SomeName";
String content = "Name $Name Date $date Signature $signature";
String result = content.replace("$Name", name);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
Name SomeName Date $date Signature $signature
```

Apply the same for the other parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am not looking something like string replace. I want to send the captured user signature to printer where it should be placed in the respective position.

Note: I have good knowledge on java :)

Answer (score 0):

[Zebra provides a Java and Android SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) which will convert images to ZPL and print it for you.  (There's actually a developer demo which shows exactly how to print signatures!).